# Issue with syncing notes in a shared folder. Don’t see new notes, created by people I share a folder

Tags: ios, icloud

Why my local note app have different folder structure then the web version on iCloud.com?

I have created a folder with notes on my iPad. I can see it on my iPhone too. I shared the folder with a friend. They can see it. Now I log in to iCloud on the web and there is not shared folder… I can see the rest of the notes but no shared folders at all.